# Integrate grafana and Azure billing

Tags: azure, grafana, azure-billing-api

I need to integrate Azure billing with Grafana

Is this possible?

How can I do it? I have searched but i dont find any solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Use the Azure Billing REST API to get data, then SimpleJson in your grafana:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/billing/

https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/grafana-simple-json-datasource

Comment: How to configure Azure billing API in SimpleJson? directly in Grafana datasource ? or a custom application to fetch API?

Comment: SimpleJson is now deprecated, please update with the new alternative (Grafana Infinity data source) https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/yesoreyeram-infinity-datasource/

Answer (score 0):

As @Thiago Custodio said, yes it is possible. You will find the connector right here:

[image]

**Be aware, however, that you are not really adding any additional value compare to the Cost Portal in Azure. Because the data persistence of the billing information is a maximum of 13 months!**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/understand-cost-mgt-data#supported-microsoft-azure-offers

[image]